# struts 2 validation on selection box

Tags: struts2

in my signUp jsp page

```
<s:select name="person.address.city.state.country.id"  list="countryList" listKey="id" listValue="name" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select"  label="Country*" cssClass="profilebox"/>
<s:select name="person.address.city.state.id" list="stateList" listKey="id" listValue="name"  headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select"  label="State*" cssClass="profilebox"/>
```

when we click on submit then no value come in this selection box.. validation is running but selection box show only select not fetch value from database in signup mode without validation code execute easily

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question it seems a puzzle to me.Some one can only help you when you will define your problem clearly so just try to rephrase your question

Comment: You should show us the corresponding struts action. Did you populate `countryList` and `stateList` at all?

Comment: show up the action class code.if list is not getting populated either you have not filed it or might have not any getter method. Any error on console/log file

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [FAQ entry on repopulating controls after validation failure](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-we-repopulate-controls-when-validation-fails.html).

Normally you'd repopulate controls using the `Preparable` interface, but you could also keep the values in the session or application context (*only* if appropriate), or use an `<s:action>` tag (sub-optimal, IMO).